# Docker Centos 7 easy_install supervisor ssl issue behind proxy

Tags: docker, ssl, centos, supervisord, easy-install

For the last two days I am reading docker-container and trying to setup an Apache container.

I am behind proxy. Below is the content of my Dockerfile.

```
FROM centos:latest
ENV http_proxy <Perfect Proxy schema here>
ENV https_proxy <Perfect Proxy schema here>
ENV ftp_proxy <Perfect Proxy schema here>
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install python-setuptools
RUN easy_install supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
RUN yum -y install which
RUN yum -y install git
```

All went good before `RUN easy_install supervisor`. I am getting the error below.

```
Step 6 : RUN easy_install supervisor
 ---> Running in 1e566719d244
Searching for supervisor
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/supervisor/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'supervisor' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for supervisor
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('supervisor')
2014/09/12 13:37:47 The command [/bin/sh -c easy_install supervisor] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also have this problem, so it's not just you

Answer (score 5):

use pip instead

```
RUN yum install -y python-pip && pip install pip --upgrade
RUN pip install --no-deps --ignore-installed --pre supervisor
```

Comment: It's worth noting that epel must be installed before you can install the python-pip package.  I.e. run this first: `RUN yum install -y epel-release`